# How to batch-render OFF-files?

Tags: 3d, file-format, 3d-modelling

I have a set of ~500 3D-Models in "Object File Format" (see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_%28file_format%29)) that I want to render for a CV-related research task.

Meshlab does offer functionality to open render each file manually, but for ~500 files this is simply too much.

Does somebody know a way how to batch-render the files?

Comment: there is a tutorial here http://www.jawa9000.com/Technical/batch/batch-rendering.htm

Comment: I also wish there was such a thing.